# Saving xlsm, after running code I cannot save my worksheet in current location

Tags: microsoft-excel

I run a vbscript to open my excel sheet and run a macro. 
however after the macro is run and I try to save it, I get this error.

[image]

I notice the location in which the file picker is not the original location, that is why this error message is coming up.

How can I keep the location the same after running my vbscript?

Here is my vbscript:

```
Set appExcel = createObject("Excel.Application")
set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
CurrentDirectory = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

appExcel.Application.Visible = True
appExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False
appExcel.Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
appExcel.Application.EnableEvents = True

appExcel.Workbooks.Open(CurrentDirectory & "\excelsheet")

appExcel.Application.Run "Run_it"

appExcel.Application.EnableEvents = False


Set appExcel = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is `CurrentDirectory`?  Where do you tell the file to save? What's the expected file save location, and the one Excel keeps using? Does your title question relate to the body? As far as I can tell, it's an issue when you're `.Open()` the file, not saving.  Also, how do you expect to open a directory? Aren't you missing something like `...Open(CurrentDirectory & "\excelsheet\myFile.xlsx")`?  Or just `..."\excelsheet.xlsx")`?

Comment: `CurrentDirectory` is correct. I dont tell the file to save, i save it manually after the macro `Run_it` has been ran. I have to go to save as and go to the location i want to save it. I can't just "save". its trying to save it in the `Network Location` folder when i do try to just "save".

Comment: When you have the file open, before you save manually, in the Immediate Window (press CTRL+G in the VBEditor), type `?thisworkbook.FullName` - what comes back? Is it a "legal" path, or are there errors/odd characters in there?

Comment: `Y:\super\user\excelsheet.xlsm` . Why is it `Y:` thats abit weird

Comment: And `CurrentDirectory` is **not** in the `Y` drive? Do you have a `Y` drive?

Comment: No I dont have one, the location of the file literally is `\\netapp\super\user\excelsheet.xlsm`

Comment: What's the `Run_it` sub? What's it do, perhaps there's something in there throwing a wrench in to things?

Comment: i run some queries to excel sheets, do some data transformations, that is all.

Comment: can i just explicity save it after the macro is ran?

Comment: Of course, see [`.SaveAs`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: but why does the location switch! Ahh!!

Comment: If you use `.SaveAs` to, say, `C:\Users\ExcelGuy\Desktop\myFile.xlsx`, does it not save there? Or does that work, and you still just can't quite figure out the original question here?

Comment: I used `.SaveAs`  it works, but i have to click `Yes` to overwrite the current file. Can I skip over this?

Comment: [Yes you can](https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+saveas+overwrite+yes)